# Mobile app development (Android) with databases and upgrade potential for friends use

Tags: android, database

What should I use ( tools, ressources, software etc...) to do the following:

I want to develop a simple app for my friends and I to keep scores for a game we play.
During a game, the app is used to keep track of life points, and when the game is finished we can register player names and other informations (like who won, who took second, with what strategy, game duration ect...). Because we don't all play together each game, we need a database and network system to synchronize results for all user of the app. This way, even if I didn't participate in the last three games, I can have the informations of who won etc...

I have zero knowledge of app development and very little knwoledge of databases but I feel that what I am asking is not too difficult. Also I would like to expand on this app to make it do more things, like display graphs for example.

What do you think I should use to get me started, and is this a doable project ?

I actively programm in python, so I have done some reasearch around that and I found Kivy but I don't know if I can do all the project with it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer how good is build an app with python and your libs, but I can present to you these hybrids and natives solutions.

You can use a hybrid framework to develop an app to iOS and Android in the same time. The most popular hybrid frameworks are:

### 1 - [React Native](https://reactnative.dev)

This one is a framework based in JavaScript with [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en). But to learn React Native, you need to learn [React](https://react.dev) first. But the learning curve is shorter than Flutter in my opinion. The official language of React Native is JavaScript. You can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) to code.

### 2 - [Flutter](https://flutter.dev)

Flutter is a hybrid solution to develop for Mobile, Desktop and Web platform. You can develop one time for all, but sometimes still needing some adjustment for each platform, and that requires that you know how to program native for these platforms. The official language for Flutter is Dart. And to create applications with Flutter you will need to use the Flutter SDK in the IDE Android Studio.

> You also can choose program natively for Android or for iOS if you only need one platform. **But attention! You only will be able to compile any app for iOS if you have a MacOS, independently of framework**. Anyway, if you want develop an Android App, you can use the native Android SDK. Google has a lot contents for free and is really good content. But [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio), the official IDE for Android development, requires a PC with at least 8GB RAM. For iOS development you need a MacOS with 4GB at least as a beginner, but is better to have 8GB RAM too. The official IDE to develop to iOS is Xcode.

### 3 - [Android Native](https://developer.android.com/)

Android Native development is the best way to make Android Apps, guarantying the best experience to the developer and final user. If you choose Android Native Development, I strongly suggest to learn Android with [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose). [Here is the first steps](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial). Jetpack Compose is the new way to build UI recommended by Google. And now exists an alpha version of Jetpack Compose for iOS too. The official programming language for Android is [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/android-overview.html) and official IDE is [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio).

Edit:
I see your edit now that your focus is Android, so I will leave here some links to help you.

- [Android Fundamentals with Jetpack Compose by Google](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-compose/course)
- [Android Advanced with Kotlin by Google](https://developer.android.com/courses/kotlin-android-advanced/overview)
- [Udacity + Google free starter Android course with Kotlin](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012)
- [Udacity + Google free advanced Android course with Kotlin](https://www.udacity.com/course/advanced-android-with-kotlin--ud940)

### 4 - [iOS Native](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

As mentioned, to start iOS development you will need a MacOS. It's a little bit more easier build apps for iOS natively than Android Native. You can start learning SwiftUI, that is like Jetpack Compose for Android. The official language for iOS is [Swift](https://www.swift.org).

### About the database

You can use a [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) product to manage your database. The Firebase has so many useful products that can really helps you save development time and you will have no worries about it. Firebase is compatible with all platforms, even hybrids. Here is the Firebase own description:

> Firebase is an app development platform that helps you build and grow apps and games users love. Backed by Google and trusted by millions of businesses around the world.

Firebase has two products for database: [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). As you say, you only will use with your friends, so the free plan should be enough for you.

In resume, that's it.
If you have any other question, just ask!

Comment: Many thanks ! There is a lot of informations to unpack here, and it seems like Android Native will be my way to go. There is a lot of documentation to work with which is the most important thing for a beginner like me

Comment: If you need something else just ask! I’m an Android Developer!